# Jenkins pipeline: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method, while executing shell script inside groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Being new to groovy, I was trying to execute shell script as part of build pipeline in Jenkins inside groovy like below :

```
stage('AMI ID EXTRACTION') {
        sh 'AMI_ID=$(grep artifact_id /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-AMI/manifest.json | awk -F "\"" '{print $4}'| awk -F ":" '{print $2}')'
        echo $AMI_ID
      }

stage ('ft-ami-extraction')
{
      build job: 'crspng-CCPDev-ami-extraction'
}
```

But ending up getting the exception like below:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'AMI_ID=$(grep
>   artifact_id
>   /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-AMI/manifest.json
>   | awk -F """ '

No luck even after trying many solutions over internet, shell script inside groovy is the challenge here. Any issue with syntax ?

Comment: For those running into similar quoting issues, [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4) might help.

Comment: you probably will need to add \ escape codes for all quotes in you line. Consider putting the whole piped-command into a shell script and running it from the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is bad. Mostly the problem I see has to do with your quoting of the shell command. This is not valid:

```
sh 'AMI_ID=$(grep artifact_id /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-AMI/manifest.json | awk -F "\"" '{print $4}'| awk -F ":" '{print $2}')'
```

You are breaking out of the single quoted string for `{print $4}`, which is probably being interpreted as a groovy closure.

I am not sure I understand why it is giving the error it is, but I think if you could most easily solve it by triple single quoting your shell command:

```
sh '''AMI_ID=$(grep artifact_id /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-AMI/manifest.json | awk -F "\"" '{print $4}'| awk -F ":" '{print $2}')'''
```

I am not sure if the next echo line will work, though, either. First of all, AMD_ID doesn't exist where you are running the `echo`. it only existed in the shell.  Also, $AMD_ID doesn't exist as a valid groovy variable. I'm not completely sure what you are attempting to do with that echo statement, but if it actually runs, it is not going to do what you expect it to do.

Comment: echo was to print the AMI_ID, I have updated the question

Comment: shell script is running now but getting  `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` , what might be wrong ?

Comment: It is probably because of this: awk -F "\""   That should probably just have a single " after the \.  Also, I still don't think `echo $AMI_ID` is going to do what you want. $AMD_ID is not declared in groovy anywhere. It is only in the shell.

Comment: I have declared the groovy variable and able to get the AMI_ID, thanks for the help.